# Delphi XE2 New Service - Why does it include these VCL units?

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2, vcl

I'm a little puzzled as to why, when you create a new service application in Delphi XE2, does it include these 3 **visual** component units?

```
Vcl.Controls
Vcl.Dialogs
Vcl.Graphics
```

As far as I know, there's nothing in these units which a Service would require. I can see the Graphics unit possibly being used for some sort of image processing, but that's a matter of a developer's implementation of it. Is there some reason why these units are automatically included in a new service application? If I remove them, it doesn't hurt anything... Or does it?

Comment: Not everything in those is visual....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Understood, but I still don't see, for example, any reason to ever have to show a dialog, because services are invisible, and should never show any dialog. And there's nothing to draw, so why is graphics included?

Comment: I have no idea, but there's only one way to find out, comment them!

Comment: Already have, as mentioned, I can remove them and nothing breaks. I'm just really puzzled as to why they would be included in the first place.

Comment: +1 good question - 'nothing breaks' is not equal to 'nothing will break later' - if the units have initializations, and they have to run for some specific code which your test did not reach yet ...

Comment: Delete them. You don't need or want them.

Comment: Nothing new here. These units are also included  in the default service app for D6 and D2010.

Comment: So adding a dialog can be done easily and then you can ask a question on here about how to get the logged on user to see it?

Comment: I don't intend on making any service interact with the user at all - I plan on making a separate tray icon app which interacts with the service through sockets - and it can be used from other computers as well through the same socket connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is added by the IDE code generator, "just in case"... 
IDE mainly creates forms, so it will add it to your service module, even if there is no need of UI in your service.

What is funny, is that since Windows Vista/Seven, the services are not able any more to send GDI messages to the desktop, i.e. interact with it. So there is definitively not even a possibility to use dialogs nor UI controls from a Windows service.

In fact, even the `SvcMgr.pas` links to `Forms.pas + Dialogs.pas` units. So deleting the reference in your own unit will continue to have those units linked.

*It appears that `Forms.pas + Dialogs.pas` units are needed by `SvcMgr.pas` to display some potential error message when the service is installed on the command line.*

In fact, your service `.exe` is not just running in the background, as a service. It can also be run from the command line, like a regular application, in order to install/uninstall/start/stop the service.

You can take a look at [our lighter implementation of Windows services in Delphi](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3Service.pas) - but not the same features - just something to play with the APIs. This version does not link to `Forms.pas` nor `Dialogs.pas` units.

Comment: *It appears that Forms.pas + Dialogs.pas units are needed by SvcMgr.pas to display some potential error message when the service is installed on the command line.* It's fine for SvcMgr to use them but there's no reason for the project template code to use them. Lots and lots of other units will be used without appearing in the project template.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course, there is no reason to use them in the project template - but, to be honest, link whole Dialogs and Forms units add a lot of unnecessary code to the service executable! So much for so little (even more with the new RTTI which makes those units not light at all, even if only one or two functions are needed).

Comment: I guess a solution (which opposes a previous question of mine) is make a complete copy of SvcMgr, remove those units, and add only the code needed by SvcMgr directly into the unit.

Comment: The `SvcMgr.pas` unit depends on the `Forms.pas` unit because `SvcMgr.TApplication` accesses `Forms.TApplication` internally.  I do not know why `SvcMgr.pas` uses `Dialogs.pas`, though.

Comment: @jerry Why are you worrying about this? It's feels annoying that so much wasted code is in the exe, but it won't get paged in to memory if it's never called so it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: I'm asking because it was a very peculiar finding. My initial question had nothing to do with what might be declared within the SvcMgr unit, I was just wondering if there was some reason why those 3 units are automatically included in a new service, because they will most likely never be used by a service. That is all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB Speaking of which, it's a wonder why the Forms.pas unit hasn't been split into two for reasons like this - there should be a separate Applications.pas unit for this in my opinion. But this is opinion.

Comment: @JerryDodge: feel free to submit a feature request to QC asking for that unit separation.